# Using Jorte, how can I see which Google Calendar an event is associated with?

Tags: calendar, jorte

Galax-S (Vibrant), Android 2.1, Jorte 1.2.5

I'm using [Jorte](http://www.appbrain.com/app/jp.co.johospace.jorte) (a replacement calendar app).  How do I see which Google Calendar a specific event is associated with?  Note that this is while viewing an existing event, not creating a new event.  When creating a new event I see the Calendar selection combo box just fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the default Calendar app, when viewing an event the individual calendar is listed right at the top. Additionally, each calendar even is color-coded.

If Jorte isn't displaying that to you, it sounds like a shortcoming of the app and something you should petition the developer to fix.

Comment: I get the colors, but unless I remember which color is which, I'm SOL.